# does every menu item in an app have an intent?

Tags: tasker, intents

In order to filter through my music better and get rid of 'stuff I know I don't want to hear again', I'm considering 'how to best go about writing a Tasker plugin' to 'delete the currently playing song'.

Detecting what's currently playing, searching for, and deleting it would be more complicated than being able to emulate the code that runs via menu item->delete->Yes dialog.

Comment: No. Every menu item doesn't need to have an `Intent`. In fact, many actions doesn't need `Intent`: deleting file, writing to DB, showing dialog, etc.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks. I've investigated several apps that purport to list the intents available in each app but haven't found the holy grail. Can you recommend a way to view all the intents an app contains? For example, a user reported that 'Action-org.prowl.torque.REQUEST_TORQUE_QUIT' is the intent to get Torque to quit. How did he find this information?

Comment: Perhaps [this related question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23687/finding-out-the-intents-an-app-uses-internally?rq=1) might help. Personally, I don't know any ways to view all app's `Intent`s, I'm afraid I can't assist further than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the AndroidManifest.xml inside the APK [the APK is just a compressed folder that you can open with WinRAR] contains a list of the available intents.